# UIPinchGestureRecognizer stops working

Tags: ios, input, touch, gesture

I used to handle touch input with touchesBegan, etc. and recently switched to gestures.  I only have three: one each of pinch, pan, and tap recognizers.  Even though my implementation is fairly simple, I've noticed a new behavior I can't explain -- touch input is occassionally lost.  It seems to occur fairly randomly, but it's pretty easy to make it happen every time if you just futz around enough.

The best example is when I'm able to get the pinch recognizer to fail.  Pinching is working, working, work, then suddently not.  No matter how many ways I try to pinch, it just won't recognize.  But then I do a tap and suddenly I can pinch again.  Since it's repeatable it would seem easy to debug, but that has not been the case.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior, or are there any suggestions where to look for what's causing it?  My only guess so far is that somehow the "state" of a gesture is getting trapped in some incomplete or erroneous, erm, state.  That's certainly one reason why some other gesture would clear it anyway.

I don't think it matters, but my gesture recognizers are attached to my only view which is a subclass of plain old UIView.

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: It now appears as though other gesture recognizers are trapping the input if your two pinch fingers don't touch down EXACTLY at the same time.  Is there any way to increase the timing tolerance for multiple touches in the pinch recognizer?  Also, is there a way to specify gesture precedence?  The "gesturemustfail" property doesn't seem to help much even though it seems like that was the intent of the property.

Comment: Any resolution to this?  I'm having the same thing happening where unless the two fingers are placed at exactly the same time the pinch gesture isn't captured.

Comment: The iOS gestures work really well in isolation, but not so well once you pile on more than two.  My solution was to rely on LongPress as a base and use other gestures only when that doesn't do the job anymore.  There are documented ways (RequireGestureToFail:) of prioritizing the gestures, but only the LongPress has parameters for tolerance in space and time.  People have also said I should write my own custom gesture recognizer and deal with all three on my own, but IMHO this time tolerance parameter is pretty basic, pretty universal, and therefore should be handled at the OS level.